# Apache proxy subdomain root requests without context name appearing

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

I am facing an absurd difficulty to perform a /context to /root using ReverseProxy between Apacher WebServer and Tomcat.

Explaining my scenario:
Sub Domains:
app01.domain.com
app02.domain.com

Tomcat:

http://localhost:8080/app01

http://localhost:8080/app02

I would like that when accessing the subdomain, the user does not see the name of the context. In my apache I have the following configuration:

ProxyPass /app01/ http://localhost:8080/app01/ retry=0

ProxyPassReverse /app01/ http://localhost:8080/app01/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app01/ retry=0

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app01/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

This works in the sense that it is not necessary to type the name of the context to access the application. However, when accessing "app01.domain.com" it inserts the context name at the end "app01.domain.com/app01".

I would really like it to be accessed without the context name appearing.

Answer (score 0):

resolvi o problema de forma simples!

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8083/app01/$1 [P]

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8083/app01/

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app02 /